# Using node js to run create or update on a large number of records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, node.js, azure, t-sql, sequelize.js

Trying to run a large script, around 700,000 records syncing from one source to a Azure database.

I'm currently using Sequelize to achieve this. When running this script it takes around 1 minute to sync 400 records which is far too slow.

I was hoping to use bulkCreate function but using the `updateOnDuplicate` method isn't compatible with `mssql` https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/model/#bulkcreaterecords-options-promisearrayinstance

How I'm achieving this so far:

**Model**

```
employees: this.sequelize.define(
      'employee',
      {
        _id: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING(24),
          primaryKey: true,
        },
        title: Sequelize.STRING,
        initials: Sequelize.STRING,
        surname: Sequelize.STRING,
        forename: Sequelize.STRING,
        middle_names: Sequelize.STRING,
        legal_surname: Sequelize.STRING,
        legal_forename: Sequelize.STRING,
        gender: Sequelize.STRING(10),
        date_of_birth_date: Sequelize.DATE
      {
        timestamps: true,
        createdAt: 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at',
        indexes: [],
      }
    ),
```

Sync code:

```
 async saveSQLResults(model: string, data: any) {
    for(const item of data) {
      const dbItem: any = await this.SQLSchemas[model]
        .findOne({ where: { _id: item._id }  });
      if(dbItem) {
        await dbItem.update(item);
      } else {
        await this.SQLSchemas[model].create(item);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do things in parallel to help speed things up. Currently your `for(const item of data)` loop is doing the find+update/create in series. Even if the DB is "slow", doing more in parallel would be faster overall.

You could try `Promise.all[]` to blast them all in parallel. Or try the [Bluebird library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) to run a few in parallel (but only up to a limit `{concurrency: 3}`).

Comment: Could they all be done in parallel considering it does at least 2 statements each find first them either create or update?

Comment: I was wondering if the fact it's slow comes from the constant sending database requires via HTTP. I have a similar setup to sync to a Mongo DB, in which I can send over 500 update with upsert, which is sent via one HTTP request, was wondering if bulkCreate function does something similar

Comment: You could do all in parallel if every item in your array was unique - but you would not want two identical items processing at the same time due to race conditions. The slow down due to network or multiple DB calls per item would all play a factor. A single command would be fastest, but I do not know if "UPSERT" exists for Aurora. You might change your entire loop into 3 sections: 1) single call to find all existing IDs of given items, 2) a single insert for all items not found, 3) and then parallel updates for each record that already exists.